# Reflection - Set Private field in controller spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, reflection

I use Spring MVC.

I have a private field in my controller. The value for this field comes from the properties file as,

```
@Controller
public Class MainController() {

   @Value("${my-value}")
   private int myValue;

}
```

I have to override the value in for the selenium tests. How can I override the value for this field, means I want to set a customized value (so that the value is not taken from property file)?

Can it be like this,

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(MainController.class, "myValue", 3, Integer.class);
```

Comment: Maybe its easier woth mocks

Comment: If it normally comes from a property file, why not have a specialized property file (activated by a Maven profile) with the values used for Selenium tests?

Comment: @mthmulders I cannot modify the property as a whole in maven which will be for all the selenium test. I want this property only for a single selenium test.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code in your controller test method.

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MainController.class, useDefaultFilters = false)
@Import({MainController.class})
public void MainControllerTest{
    @Autowired
    private MainController mainController

    @Test
    should_set_controller_private_field(){
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(mainController, "myValue", 3)
        assertEquals(ReflectionTestUtils.getField(
            mainController, "myValue"), 3)
    }
}
```